# #include<Folder/Header.h> gives error in one .h but not in another

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, include

I am trying to reproduce a demo project bundled with an external framework.
I have used Build Phases-Copy Files and -Link Binary with Libraries to bring the framework into the project.
I have copied two sets of .h /.m files from the demo project into my version.

Both Class1.h and Class2.h have `#include<FolderName/FrameworkName.h>`.
In Class1.h I have an error: `'FolderName/FrameworkName.h' file not found'`.
But in Class2.h there is no error.

**How can I get rid of this error? And why doesn't it affect both .h files?**

In the demo project the filepath of the FrameworkName.h is `/Project/FolderName/Universal/FrameworkName.framework/Headers/FrameworkName.h`
Which works fine with the `#include<FolderName/FrameworkName.h>` statement.
In my project I have emulated the file structure of the demo version.

*NB I'm only a rookie Swift programmer - very basic understanding of Ob-C. Thank you!

Comment: can you please show your folder structure in code? if possible.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Is there a way to do that apart from writing it all out? Thanks